# empathetic eye or the eye of an insider?

Tags: word-choice, academia

I am a student going abroad from a developing country to study in a developed one for 2 years already. Now i am looking for research job in the developed countries. Regarding migration of labor, can I say I have the eye of an insider? or just the empathetic eye? I feel like I can understand the migrants for a better work and better life, but I don't feel like I have experienced the hardships as much as they do. So I am confused about expressing the feeling. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a better way to express your idea would be:  "I can empathize with their situation." or "I have empathy with this group...based on x, y, z."